# Configure Q-municate demo of Quickblox in Android Studio

Tags: android, quickblox-android, q-municate

I am just trying to configure demo of Q-municate suggested by Quickblox from https://quickblox.com/developers/Q-municate#2._Login_to_QuickBlox_admin_panel but I am getting following error while trying to Sync :

```
Gradle sync failed: Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :q-municate_base_service: - debugApiElements - debugRuntimeElements - releaseApiElements - releaseRuntimeElements All of them match the consumer attributes: - Configuration 'debugApiElements': - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required. - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required. - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements': - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required. - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required. - Configuration 'releaseApiElements': - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required. - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required. - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements': - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required. - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required. - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required. Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (840ms)
```

Please get me out of it. Thanks